# jquery autocomplete How to set label and how to get value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dynamic input field created with class name as sub-category.
On key press autocomplete is working fine, from which i can select one.

Working code for that is below

```
$("body").on('keypress', 'input.sub-category', function () {
        var availableTags = [
            {label:"ActionScript", value:"1"},
            {label:"ActionScript1", value:"11"},
            {label:"ActionScript2", value:"12"},
            {label:"ActionScript3", value:"13"},
            {label:"ActionScript4", value:"14"},
        ];
        $(this).autocomplete({
            source: availableTags,
        });
    });
```

When i select one of the autosuggested text say 'ActionScript', it's value (1) should be available in the below code, how i can access it? On select alert function is working fine, so just need to know how to access value of the selected label.

```
$("body").on('autocompleteselect', 'input.sub-category', function () {
        alert('here');
});
```

In addition to that i would like to know how to set the selected text in the input box rather than it's value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to include jquery-ui file
"https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js" in your file
and
just replace

```
 $("body").on('autocompleteselect', 'input.sub-category', function () {
        alert('here');
});
```

with the following lines.

```
$("body").on('autocompleteselect', 'input.sub-category', function (event,ui)     {
    alert(ui.item.label);
    alert(ui.item.value);

});
```

and

```
$(this).autocomplete({
        source: availableTags,
    });
```

with

```
$(this).autocomplete({
        source: availableTags,
        select:function(event,ui){
           $(".sub-category").val(ui.item.label);return false;
        }
    });
```

and this will work fine for more info please go on following link

http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: ReferenceError: ui is not defined.   i got this error when i tried.

Answer (score 1):

More than easy!

It's here http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select
And it says, that You may bind handler in such manner
`$( ".selector" ).on( "autocompleteselect", function( event, ui ) {} );`
where `ui` is Object which has `item` which in turn has selected `label` and `value` data.